# How do I get the correct output?

Tags: java, math

So for this, I seem to be only getting "Infinity" for the dollar amount of the output. I think it has something to do with the math. (Don't mind the sloppy code, I was told to debug it without altering it too much) That's the only problem I seem to be having. Other than that everything else works fine.

```
/* Chapter 3 Debugging Assignment
 *Programmer:
 *Date:
 *Program Name: Bert,java
 *Purpose:
 */

import java.util.Scanner;

public class bert {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Declaring Variables
        int price, downPayment, tradeIn, months, loanAmt, interest;
        double annualInterest, payment;
        String custName;

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Get Input from User
        System.out.println("What is your first name? ");
        custName = reader.next();
        System.out.print("What is the price of the car? ");
        price = reader.nextInt();
        System.out.print("What is the downpayment? ");
        downPayment = reader.nextInt();
        System.out.print("What is the trade-in value? ");
        tradeIn = reader.nextInt();
        System.out.print("For how many months is the loan? ");
        months = reader.nextInt();
        System.out.print("What is the decimal interest rate? ");
        annualInterest = reader.nextDouble();

        //Output
        calculatePayment(price, downPayment, tradeIn, (int) annualInterest, months);
    }

    public static void calculatePayment(int price, int downPayment, int tradeIn,
            int months, double annualInterest) {

        double interest;
        int loanAmt;
        double payment;

        //Calculations
        interest = (double) annualInterest/ (double) 12 ;
        loanAmt = (int) (price - downPayment - tradeIn);
        payment = loanAmt / ((1.0 / interest) - (1.0 / (interest * Math.pow(1.0, annualInterest))));
        String custName = "Any Name";

        System.out.print("The monthly payment for ");
        System.out.print(custName + " is $ ");
        System.out.println((double) payment);

        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: @MadProgrammer actually he doesn't. The next call will skip over the newline.

Comment: Tell me @panzo, why are you passing the interest rate (converted to an `int`, so with the decimal part chopped off) as the number of months, and the number of months as the interest rate?

Comment: @immibis You know, I really hate `Scanner`

Comment: @immibis Which lines? I'm sorry, I'm new to coding.

Comment: @panzo cliff2310 said it already

Comment: Still it comes out as inifinty.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments for calculatePayment don't match.  
 calculatePayment(price, downPayment, tradeIn, (int) annualInterest, months);should be
 calculatePayment(price, downPayment, tradeIn, **months**, **annualInterest**);
Your math is bad.
*Math.pow(1.0, annualInterest)* is **always** 1. 
so you have *1/interest - 1/interest* which is 0.  then you have loanAmt/0.0 ==> **Infinity**
Go back and check you payment calculations

Comment: I changed that but it still runs as infinity, is it a problem with the math or the code itself.